# I can build and run my project but my IDE keeps showing errors

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans, compiler-errors, dependencies

I am working on a gradle project. I have no issue building and running my project with gradle and seeing the output. However, in my both NetBeans and Eclipse the following lines are underlined in red:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
```

The error is:

> package xxx does not exist

This is actually quite annoying because it means I have no auto-completion and no real ability to detect legitimate build errors before trying to build.

Restarting the IDE does not help. Clean and build does not help. I installed the gradle plugin too, but nothing changed.

How can I change my settings so that NetBeans recognizes this as a gradle project and picks up my dependencies?

My `build.gradle`, as requested in the comments:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'server.Server'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.0.0'
    implementation 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5.5'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'
}
```

**Edit**

The build script works fine normally, but when I check the project into source control and then check it out on another machine, the problem shows up. I meant to be very clear about that in my original post, but I think I failed.

Comment: This is not enough info to solve the issue. Since you are saying that you have the same issue with 2 IDEs, it is probably a problem with your build script. Can you build it from the command line? Regardless, you should link the build script (or a sample with which you experience the same issue).

Comment: @AttilaKelemen Posted the build.gradle as you asked. As I said in my question, I have no issue building using gradle from the command line. I cannot build normally from the command line. I suspect that somehow the version checked into source control is missing classpath information or something like that. However, I don't know what file to include in git that would fix that, or how to confirm that that is the problem.

Comment: Your build script works fine for me in NB. Could it be that you are using a different version of Gradle in the IDE? In NB you can change the used Gradle version in the project properties.

Comment: Build script works fine for me too if I create a new project. It doesn't work only when I check out my project from git on another machine. Sorry if that was not clear from the question

Comment: The SCM shouldn't have any effect. Maybe there is a symlink in the path? Have you tried checking your sources out into another directory (or move the project to another directory manually)?

Comment: @AttilaKelemen I have checked out the project into many directories on two different computers. The only version that works fine is the original project I created, any version checked out from source seems broken (as in it builds using gradle but not from the IDE)

Comment: Have you tried if it builds if you are building from NB and not from the command line? Anyway, you issue seems to be very strange (I have never heard anything like that), so I recommend you to open an issue here: https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/issues I will probably have to ask you to do a little debugging, since I cannot reproduce the issue (the plugin pretty much builds out of the box, so it shouldn't be difficult).

Comment: @AttilaKelemen it's definitely not an issue with the netbeans gradle project, since it happens in every IDE. thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really stupid, but I was trying to import the project as an eclipse project. If you just clone the project and open it normally (with the NetBeans gradle plugin installed) it will work.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue some time ago. The only thing helped to me was clearing NetBeans cache. On Windows operating system it is located under `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache` folder, on Linux operating systems under `/home/<user>/.cache/netbeans` one. So, what I did was closed NetBeans, deleted folders inside the specified one, and started NetBeans again.